# Getting values from Hashtable on Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, wcf

I have a simple login system using a WCF Service which gives me a hashtable with the values of the session.

The login method receives a hashtable with user and pass, and returns a hashtable with the session information.

The hashtable is serialized with ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json in the services interface.

What I'm getting is a Array of objects with a Key and Value

```
{
   "LoginResult":[
      {
         "Key":"role",
         "Value":1
      },
      {
         "Key":"welcome",
         "Value":"Bem-vindo, User1"
      },
      {
         "Key":"loggedin",
         "Value":1
      }
   ]
}
```

So I'm not sure how to get the Values of each Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the `LoginResult` and get a map as follows, assuming you have a variable named `loginResult` that has assigned the `LoginResult` property of your response:

```
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < loginResult.length; i++) {
    result[loginResult[i].Key] = loginResult[i].Value;
}

console.log(result);
```

This would show:

```
{
    "role": 1,
    "welcome": "Bem-vindo, User1",
    "loggedin": 1
}
```

and you can use each property as follows for example perform a validation:

```
if (result.role === 1 && result.loggedin === 1) {
    console.log('Login Succesful!');
}
```